# where is the db backup location when deleting a website

Tags: websites

i'm pending to delete a website via Manage Stores, i checked "
Create DB Backup", but i don't know how it backup, backup what? and where is the backup files will be stored?

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in var/backups folder.

Comment: full db backup?

Comment: Yes.A zip will be created in that folder

Answer (score 0):

it will store on your server, where your all files are placed.
check the var folder